# bash - mass renaming files with many special characters

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, rename, batch-rename

I have a lot of files (in single directory) like:

```
[a]File-. abc'.d -001[xxx].txt
```

so there are many spaces, apostrophes, brackets, and full stops. The only differences between them are numbers in place of `001`, and letters in place of `xxx`.
How to remove the middle part, so all that remains would be

```
[a]File-001[xxx].txt
```

I'd like an explanation how such code would work, so I could adapt it for other uses, and hopefully help answer others similar questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple script in pure `bash`:

```
for f in *; do            # for all entries in the current directory
  if [ -f "$f" ]; then    # if the entry is a regular file (i.e. not a directory)
    mv "$f" "${f/-*-/-}"  # rename it by removing everything between two dashes 
                          # and the dashes, and replace the removed part 
                          # with a single dash
  fi
done
```

The magic done in the `"${f/-*-/-}"` expression is described in the bash manual (the command is `info bash`) in the chapter **3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion**

The `*` pattern in the first line of the script can be replaced with anything than can help to narrow the list of the filles you want to rename, e.g. `*.txt`, `*File*.txt`, etc.

Comment: Yes, its works! At first I got "1.sh: 3: 1.sh: Bad substitution", but then i edited script to exclude file in which its located. (*.txt), and it worked. I also played a little with editing it to be sure I get how it works. Thank you Rajish.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the `rename` (aka `prename`) utility that's a part of Perl distribution, you could say:

```
rename -n 's/([^-]*-).*-(.*)/$1$2/' *.txt
```

to rename all txt files in your desired format.  The `-n` above would **not** perform the actual rename, it'd only **tell** you what it would do had you not specified it.  (In order to perform the actual rename, remove `-n` from the above command.)

For example, this would rename the file

```
[a]File-. abc'.d -001[xxx].txt
```

as

```
[a]File-001[xxx].txt
```

---

Regarding the explanation, this captures the part upto the first `-` into a group, and the part after the second (or last) one into another and combines those.

Read about [Regular Expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).  If you have perl docs available on your system, saying `perldoc perlre` should help.